# "Create React App" with Docker

Tags: reactjs, docker, webpack, docker-compose, livereload

I was wondering if anyone had any experience using create-react-app with docker. I was able to get it set up with a Dockerfile like:

```
from node
RUN mkdir /src
WORKDIR /src
ADD package.json /src/package.json
RUN npm install
EXPOSE  3000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

And then used a docker-compose file like:

```
app:
  volumes:
    - "./app:/src"
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
    - "35729:35729"
  build: ./app
```

This allowed me to start up the container and view the app. However livereload didn't work when saving files in the mounted volume and webpack created several .json.gzip files in the src directory.

Any suggestions for getting this working correctly?

Comment: I think docker is not the right tool for what you want to have. Just develop on yout machine with live reloading and other features you like and build containers/images for released version only or for automated testing... It's not clear why you need docker for development here...

Comment: livereload should work if you're using Docker for Mac, or using docker on linux. If you're still using Docker Toolbox (with a VM) it has been reported that file watching often doesn't work.

Comment: @dnephin thanks for the tip switched to Docker for Mac and everything works great.

Comment: @aholbreich I think you might be right, my thought was to wrap everything (including the backend i'm working on) in a docker compose setup to deal with CORS but I think that is likely overkill.

Answer (score 9):

Yeah, as aholbreich mentioned, I'd use `npm install` / `npm start` locally on my machine for development, just because it's so easy. It's probably possible with `docker-compose`, mounting volumes etc. too, but I think it could be a bit fiddly to set up.

For deployment you can then very easily use a Dockerfile. Here's an example Dockerfile I'm using:

```
FROM node:6.9

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /src/app
WORKDIR /src/app

# to make npm test run only once non-interactively
ENV CI=true

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /src/app/
RUN npm install && \
    npm install -g pushstate-server

# Bundle app source
COPY . /src/app

# Build and optimize react app
RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 9000

# defined in package.json
CMD [ "npm", "run", "start:prod" ]
```

You need to add the `start:prod` option to your *package.json*:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  "start:prod": "pushstate-server build",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
```

You can run the tests on your CI service with:

```
docker run <image> npm test
```

There's nothing stopping you from running this docker container locally as well to make sure things work as expected.

Comment: I downvoted this because it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: How does this not answer the question? It's a useful answer with 'suggestions for getting this working correctly'.

Comment: @Midiman on my local machine i can only run docker containers, no other run times like node/npm, so this does not answer the question.

Answer (score 7):

I recently made a small project called hello-docker-react who just does what the op is looking for.

It's made with docker-compose, create-react-app, yarn, a node image, and a small entrypoint script.

Live reload work flawlessly and I haven't found any problems yet.

https://github.com/lopezator/hello-docker-react

Answer (score 4):

here is good gide for this 
https://mherman.org/blog/dockerizing-a-react-app/

for development

```
# base image
FROM node:9.6.1

# set working directory
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# add `/usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@1.1.1 -g --silent

# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

for production

```
# build environment
FROM node:9.6.1 as builder
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@1.1.1 -g --silent
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN npm run build

# production environment
FROM nginx:1.13.9-alpine
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Comment: How will you distinguish the docker file for dev and prod ? With different names?

Comment: Yes, names or different folders

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly a direct improvement of the author's code, but I was able to get a development environment working with very little code - and no direct dependency to node on my machine - like this:

#### docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  node:
    image: node:16
    user: "node"
    command: "npm start"
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
```

This way, you avoid creating docker images from a `Dockerfile`.

Usage is generally like this:

- install dependencies before running: `docker compose run node npm install`
- run development environment: `docker compose up`
- install new dependencies: `docker compose run node npm install [package name]`
- clean up docker instances created with `compose run`: `docker compose rm`

Answer (score 1):

While using docker in development with create-react-app, i discovered that it is possible to override the webpackDevServer configuration by adding `CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=1`to your .env file. This will make the file watching work again. It even refreshes the browser page on the host! The only thing that i discovered is that it doesn't open up a webpage automatically.

I can also advise to add `tty: true` to your service to have your original console output back into your terminal. To remove the container name prefixes in the logs, you can run something like this after running `docker-compose up -d`:

```
docker-compose logs -f --tail=100 client | cut -f2 -d \"|\""
```

Answer (score 1):

Running with CRA 4.0 and many dependencies

.dockerignore

```
.git
.gitignore
node_modules
build
```

Dockerfile.dev

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json /app

RUN yarn install

COPY . .

CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

docker-compose.dev.yml

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  print:
    stdin_open: true
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ".:/app"
      - "/app/node_modules"
```

Dockerfile.prod

```
FROM node:alpine as build

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json /app

RUN yarn install

COPY . /app

RUN yarn run build

FROM nginx:stable-alpine
COPY ./nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

docker-compose.prod.yml

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  print:
    stdin_open: true
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

nginx.conf

```
server {  
  listen 80;
  server_name frontend;
  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }
}
```

To run

```
docker-compose.exe -f .\docker-compose.yml up --build
```

or

```
docker-compose.exe -f .\docker-compose.dev.yml up --build
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple (pure docker) solution without local installation of runtime (e.g. node):

```
cd /tmp
docker run -it --rm -v "$PWD":/app -w /app node  yarn create react-app my-app
sudo chown -R $USER:root my-app/
cd my-app
nano docker-compose.yml  # see docker-compose.yml below
docker compose up -d
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
  services:
      node:
        image: node:16-alpine
        environment:
          - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
          - FAST_REFRESH=true
        working_dir: /app
        ports:
          - '3000:3000'
        command: "yarn start"
        volumes:
          - './:/app'
```

open [localhost:3000](https://localhost:3000) in your browser. Hot reload should work out of the box.